# Sum rows under conditions in R

Tags: r

I would like to sum rows of two columns based on a condition of a variable "country". The output should give a new column that has only values for specified countries and NA's for the rest. For instance:

```
P  R  Country Total
1  1  IT       2
2  2  DE       4
3  3  FR       NA
4  4  FR       NA
5  5  DE       10
6  6  IT       12
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ifelse` for this:

```
your_data$Total = with(your_data, ifelse(Country %in% c("IT", "DE"), P + R, NA))
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: With other variables, it gives me NA's. I tried `as.numeric` but it did not help. Do you know what it might be?

Comment: Nope. Ask a new question [and share some data reproducibly as described here.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/903061)